# I want to export a file as JSON but it gives an error

Tags: python, json, csv, export

I want to get the outputs given in Terminal as a file. But I couldn't get it. It keeps giving error. How can I get these codes as files instead of terminal?

```
from youtubesearchpython import \*

'''
Searches for all types of results like videos, channels & playlists in YouTube.
'type' key in the JSON/Dictionary may be used to differentiate between the types of result.
'''
allSearch = Search('NoCopyrightSounds', limit = 1, language = 'en', region = 'US')
print(allSearch.result())

'''
Searches only for videos in YouTube.
'''
videosSearch = VideosSearch('NoCopyrightSounds', limit = 10, language = 'en', region = 'US')

print(videosSearch.result(mode = ResultMode.json))
```

'''
'''`

import json

VideosSearch = {}

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
json.dump(VideosSearch, outfile)

I tried this but it gave an error.

```
   json.dump(videosSearch, outfile)
  File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 437, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'VideosSearch' is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: It is helpful to include the error in your post when you have an error. Please add the error message to your post.

Comment: now i posted the error.

Comment: The problem seems pretty clear from the error message — you can't JSON serialize a `VideosSearch`. The `json` module can only serialize certain Python data structures (shown in this [table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder)) and `VideosSearch` isn't one of them. You will need to manually convert it into one or more things which *can* be.